# Python redirect to URL not working

Tags: javascript, python, url, redirect, cgi

I know there are other posts on this, but I've tried everything I can think of and still can't get a simple redirect working as a CGI script on a Linux server. I've tried 3 different methods and none of them works. I know some people will suggest removing the first two print statements after the import, but that gives me 500 Server error. All I'm trying to do is have the browser redirect to another URL when this python CGI script is called.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi, cgitb 
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print

def go_to_url(url):
    print "HTTP/1.1 302 Found"
    print "Location: ",url,"\r\n"
    print "Connection: close \r\n"
    print " "

def go_to_url2(url):
    print ('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = ' + url + ';</script>')

def go_to_url3(url):
    print '<html><head><script type="text/javascript">'
    print '<!-- function jump(){window.location = "' + url + '" } //-->'
    print '</script></head><body onLoad="jump()"></body></html>'

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
# go_to_url(url)    
# go_to_url2(url)   
go_to_url3(url)
```

Comment: I tried another solution using webbrowser module, but that failed too. I know the script runs because when I insert a Hello World print statement it prints to the screen. This seems like a server problem, not code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This works. Other important problems to note, 
1. when developing on a Windows system make sure to change the line endings to Linux format
2. chmod the python file to 755.

```
def go_to_url(url):
    print ('<html><header><script type="text/javascript">window.location ="' + url + '";</script></header><body><p>Redirect2</p></body></html>')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to keep in mind that the HTTP version should be dynamic by the client's browser, you shouldn't force it.

Javascript solution for HTTP redirect creates more overhead in performance.

Because 1st request is for an HTML page with the JS redirect code, then a 2nd request is for the redirect itself ( two requests in total vs one )

I believe you can't redirect after you've printed `print "Content-Type: text/html"`.

Your script should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi 

def print_http_header():
    print "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    print

def go_to_url(url):
    # HTTP version ( 1.0 / 1.1 / 2.0 ) should be determine by browser
    print "Status: 302 Moved"
    print "Location: %s" % url
    print

def go_to_url2(url):
    print_http_header()
    print ('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = ' + url + ';</script>')

def go_to_url3(url):
    print_http_header()
    print '<html><head><script type="text/javascript">'
    print '<!-- function jump(){window.location = "' + url + '" } //-->'
    print '</script></head><body onLoad="jump()"></body></html>'

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
# go_to_url(url)    
# go_to_url2(url)   
go_to_url3(url)
```

Hope that helps....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I hope this helps. It worked for me!

```
print ("Status: 302 Moved")
print ("Location: http://www.somedomain.com/")
print() # HTTP says you have to have a blank line between headers and content
```